# How to create a Class that I can reuse in multiple modules?

Tags: 8, hooks

I would like to create a class that has a set of methods that I want to reuse across the site in either mytheme.theme or secondmodule.module files.

How would I create this class and class methods so that they can be used in multiple areas? Would I have to create a custom module for this?

Here is what I was trying so far, but need assistance on next step.

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\CustomClass;

class MyClass {
  public static function processEntity($var1, $var2) {
    /* process the parameters */
    return value;
  }
}
```

If I wanted to use this in a mytheme.theme file I was thinking to do this

```
<?php

use Drupal\CustomClass\MyClass;

function _some_function() {
  /* processing logic here which results in $var1, $var2 */
  $results = MyClass::processEntity($var1, $var2);
}
```

Comment: modulename/src/MyClass.php .... use \Drupal\modulename\MyClass

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your use case is where Drupal 8 [services](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/services-and-dependency-injection-in-drupal-8) come into play. When you'd like to create classes/methods that can be used across Drupal by other modules and your theme, create a custom module that provides this class as a service. You can then get an instance of this service class by either using the static service getter `\Drupal::service()` within `*.module` or `*.theme` files, or dependency injection in other classes/services.

Comment: the classes and methods were initially planned as static methods where you pass it some values and it performs some processing, but reading further on the Services, that provided more options. Thanks for the links

Comment: I think this approach is great, but do you see an issue with having other modules or themes dependent on this module for the service? It seems like this approach would only work if the custom module ONLY included this service and did nothing else.

Comment: Not really. A wide variety of contributed modules provide service classes and auxiliary functionality. The same goes for your custom modules. You can add as many services as you please and also do additional things as hook implementations, event listeners and so on. As long as it makes sense for this module. If it provides services for other classes of just one of your custom modules, you might consider adding the service straight to this dependent module. Overall, the architecture using services can be highly flexible, tailored to your very special needs.

Comment: This tutorial simply explains how to use service in controller https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/drupal8-under-the-hood/what-is-the-service-container#play

Answer (score 3):

Making a service of a class that only contains static methods wouldn't make any sense because it is not intended to be used as an instance.

To answer your question; Yes you need to put your class in a module. And then you would have to namespace it properly and put a line similar to the following one at the beginning of the file.

```php
namespace Drupal\your_module;
```

The class would then be placed in the module's *src* folder of your module.

You would use that class by adding the following line on the top of the  .theme file.

```php
use Drupal\your_module\MyClass;
```

I would also recommend to explicitly add an dependency on the other modules that would use that module's class. Starting with Drupal 8.9, [theme's can now declare modules as dependencies](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/474684#comment-13513415).

Comment: Whereas the OP didn't provide any information, of whether his helper methods are static only, services make perfect sense for any public helpers anyway. E.g. in terms of extendability. Introducing services for common classes/methods - and using dependency injection/static getters when accessing them - allows other modules to override these services when required (e.g. within their services.yml or a ServiceProvider implementation).

Comment: Sure, however given the code examples it looks intended to use static methods. In general I agree with your opinion but it's not scope of the question whet ever it should be so or not. Instead we have 2 suitable answers either way how OP can create and reuse his services/utility classes.

Comment: the scope of the question was for a static method, but after reading further into Services, that approach seemed more worth the effort.